# Appending a % on the end of a calculated value in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculated-field

I have a form that calculates a few values and spits out a grade. I would like to have the grade be a precent. They already come out as integers, ie: 100.00.

```
var acqAmount1 = Number(jQuery("#edit-submitted-acquisition-amount-1").val().replace(/,/g,""));
    var acqAmount2 = Number(jQuery("#edit-submitted-acquisition-amount-2").val().replace(/,/g,""));
    var acqTotal = 0;

    if (acqAmount1) {
        acqAmount1 = parseFloat(acqAmount1);
    } else {
        acqAmount1 = 0;
    }

    if (acqAmount2) {
        acqAmount2 = parseFloat(acqAmount2);
    } else {
        acqAmount2 = 0;
    }

    if (acqAmount1 > 0 && acqAmount2 > 0) {
        acqTotal = ((acqAmount2 - acqAmount1) / acqAmount1 * 100).toFixed(2);
    } else {
        acqTotal = 0;
    }

    jQuery("#edit-submitted-acquisition-percent-change").val( acqTotal );

    grade += getAcquisitionPoints(acqTotal);




<fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 2</h3>
            <!-- Begin Total Number of Donors in Year 1 Field -->
                <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_total_number_of_donors_in_year_1 field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-acquisition--amount-1">

                    <label for="edit-submitted-acquisition-amount-1 total_number_of_donors_in_year_1-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_6344">What was your number of total donors in year 1?</label><span class="required"> * </span>

                    <input id="edit-submitted-acquisition-amount-1" class="form-text hs-input" name="submitted total_number_of_donors_in_year_1" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number">
                    <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                        <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            <!-- End Total Number of Donors in Year 1 Field -->

            <!-- Begin Total Number of Donors in Year 2 Field -->
                <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield hs_total_number_of_donors_in_year_2 field hs-form-field" id="webform-component-acquisition--amount-2">

                    <label for="edit-submitted-acquisition-amount-2 total_number_of_donors_in_year_2-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_6344">What was your number of total donors in year 2?</label><span class="required"> * </span>

                    <input id="edit-submitted-acquisition-amount-2" class="form-text hs-input" name="submitted[acquisition][amount_2] total_number_of_donors_in_year_2" required="required" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter a valid number">
                    <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
                        <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <!-- End Total Number of Donors in Year 2 Field -->

            <!-- Begin Calc of Total Number of Donors Fields -->
            <!-- THIS FIELD IS NOT EDITABLE | GRAYED OUT -->
                <div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-container-inline hs_total_donor_percent_change field hs-form-field">

                    <label for="edit-submitted-acquisition-percent-change total_donor_percent_change-99a6d115-5e68-4355-a7d0-529207feb0b3_6344">Total Donors Percent Change</label><span class="required"> * </span>

                    <input id="edit-submitted-acquisition-percent-change" class="form-text hs-input" name="total_donor_percent_change" readonly="readonly" size="60" maxlength="128" type="number" value="" placeholder="0"><span class="field-suffix">%</span>
                </div>
                <!-- End Calc of Total Number of Donors Fields -->
        <input type="button" data-page="2" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" data-page="2" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        <div class="explanation btn btn-small modal-trigger" data-modal-id="modal-3">What Is This?</div>
    </fieldset>
```

I have tried a few ways of `+= '%'` `+ '%'` but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Doesn't `grade = grade + '%';` work?

Comment: `jQuery("#edit-submitted-acquisition-percent-change").val( acqTotal + '%' );` doesn't work?

Comment: @D4V1D `grade += getAcquisitionPoints(acqTotal);
  grade = grade + '%';` does not fire any errors, but also does not append the '%' :/

Comment: Probably `#edit-submitted-acquisition-percent-change` is a form `input` of `type="number"`. Can you show it's HTML? Do you see any errors?

Comment: What does `console.log(grade);` ouputs? Also, could you give a try to `grade = grade.toString();`?

Comment: @Phylogenesis I have tried that, it stops my calculations from working and does not throw an error.

Yes, it is a form input of 'number' will update question to include html

Comment: @D4V1D `Console.log(grade)` returns a `0` from start, then `100` when filled.

Comment: Here is the most basic example and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9kbgbwto/ Please show the version of your code where it was *not* working. If you have a numeric only field it will filter out the non-numeric characters.

Comment: You can't use a `%` symbol in a `type=number` field; setting `val` will fail. Since your field is `readonly`, why don't you just use a `type=text` field? `parseFloat` will still parse the number properly.

Comment: first of all, your grade is not defined. you can not append a value into the undefined variable. So define your `var grade = 0;` before.  after, you can append like `.val(acqTotal+ '%');` its works, try it here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1s3nmn35/1/)

Comment: @Jean-philippeEmond

The file is near 1500lines, this is in the middle, my calulation works, it just won't show an appended `%`. I believe it might be because I have a field type of number

Comment: @Schism will that filter symbols added dynamically as well?

Comment: @user4875251 yes.. you can not add other thing in the number type. But add % outside of the box?... it's a weird question but.. the type=number is useD for number... so.. why you try to put another thing that's not a number on it?

Comment: I mean that setting `val` to something with non-digit characters is illegal and will fail. If you change to type to `text`, then it'll be allowed. Then, when you're parsing its value, `parseFloat` will parse up to the first non-digit character and then stop, so it should still function. If you're adding symbols to the beginning or the end, you'll need to filter them out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the target `input` element from:

```
type="number"
```

To:

```
type="text"
```

Should fix the issue. Use:

```
jQuery("#edit-submitted-acquisition-percent-change").val( acqTotal + '%' );
```

Comment: Yup, this is it, solved it!

Thanks to Schism and PeterKA, they both provided answers to the problem. Appreciate the help!